# VMWare Horizon and SecurID. Prompted for SecurID passcode and Windows password at login

Tags: securid, vmware-horizon-view

We use a mix of Windows 10 desktops and VMWare Horizon desktop pools.

We recently deployed RSA SecurID tokens to some of our users. On the physical desktops, authentication works as it should: On first login, users create a PIN, then enter their Windows password. After that, they only enter their RSA passcode (PIN plus the code on their token). They never need to enter their Windows password again.

The zero clients, however, are different. Before reaching the Windows VMs, Horizon challenges them for their passcode, followed by their Windows password. So our users have to remember the PIN for the passcode as well as their Windows password.

Is there a setting in Horizon that will allow users to authenticate using only their passcode?